# Laravel: isDirty() always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm trying to detect when the model gets updates and when it has no update using `isDirty()`, Is something missing?

```
        $user = User::updateOrCreate(['email' => $line['Email']],[
            'username'      => $line['Username'],
            'fname'         => $line['First_name'],
            'lname'         => $line['Surname'],
            'email'         => $line['Email'],
        ]);

        dd($user->isDirty()); // always return false


        User::updating(function ($user) {
            dd($user->isDirty());  // always returns true
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

That function is for something more like this:

```
// $user = user pulled from database
$user->isDirty(); // returns false 

$user->name = "newName";
$user->email = "newEmail@email.com";

$user->isDirty(); // returns true

$user->save();
$user->isDirty(); // returns false
```

Comment: What shall I use rather than isDirty()?

Comment: There is a wasChanged() function which will tell you if you have recently updated the model with a ->save().  you could also do getChanges() which will let you know if anything has been changed (and what they are) recently.  I would refer to the Laravel documentation for compatibility with your version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out if a user was `created` or `updated` you can do the following:

If the user was created:

```php
$user->wasRecentlyCreated
```

If the user was updated and a value was changed:

```php
$user->wasChanged()
```

Beware that if nothing was changed it will return false

Answer (score 0):

You are just querying the database not updating the model

*[isDirty](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty)* function works if you wish to know if the *model* or given attribute has been changed since the last sync from the database.

Comment: What shall I use?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `isDirty()` function:

When `updateOrCreate` method called then your model data saved. so after call `isDirty()` method always returns false. Because data already saved.

```
User::updateOrCreate()
```

Laravel `updating()` means data collected for an update but not updated you know.

**Use of `idDirty()`**
You might come up with a situation where you want to check if a given Eloquent attribute was changed compared with its original stored value.